# How to pass Timestamp to Oracle Function?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, ora-00936

I have a table and storing date value in it and I need to fetch that value and pass that as parameter to function. But whenever I try to execute my code it's throwing error like

```
ORA-00936: missing expression.
```

Following is my code sample:

```
SELECT refno, 
       Tatcalculate(to_timestamp(SELECT h_modified_date
                                   FROM TPADETAILS
                                  WHERE refno = 'WOC0021946','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
 FROM Table1;
```

`Table1` is my table and `h_modified_date` is the column. `Tatcalculate()` is the function.

When I run inner query it's returning the date value from the table but when I execute complete above query then its throwing the error.
Anybody please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the `to_timestamp()` around the column name, rather than around the select statement.

Also, you need to enclose the select statement in its own brackets. Thus:

```
SELECT refno, Tatcalculate((SELECT to_timestamp(h_modified_date,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM TPADETAILS WHERE refno='WOC0021946'))
FROM Table1;
```

ETA: Given the extra information that the tatcalculate parameter is DATE datatype and also the h_modified_date column is a DATE, there is absolutely no need to do any datatype conversions at all. Therefore, the query becomes:

```
SELECT refno, Tatcalculate((SELECT h_modified_date FROM TPADETAILS WHERE refno='WOC0021946'))
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: I have already tried that one and I got error as **ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string**

Comment: what is the datatype of the h_modified_date column?

Comment: DATE and in function also the parameter type is DATE

Comment: so if the parameter is in DATE format, why on earth are you trying to pass a timestamp in? Especially when the column is already in DATE format? Remove the `to_timestamp()` - it's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

give column name

> SELECT refno, Tatcalculate(to_timestamp(SELECT  h_modified_date FROM
>   TPADETAILS WHERE refno='WOC0021946','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) as TAT
>   FROM Table1;

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
SELECT refno, Tatcalculate(to_timestamp((SELECT  to_char(h_modified_date,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM TPADETAILS WHERE refno='WOC0021946'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
FROM Table1;
```